# How to change sprocket's temp cache directory for rails app to another file location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-machine, virtualbox, nfs, sprockets

I'm running my development environment inside of a Ubuntu VM hosted by a Windows OS, so I'm using a windows-hosted NFS which the VM uses. I've been having problems lately with 'too-quick' file access (sprockets tries to unlink a file but fails, and I can do so manually only seconds later). This frequent problem shows up as: `Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /home/vagrant/rails/dev.website/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/v3.0/[some-random-string]`. This crops up with different asset references every time, so I know it's not a problem with the files themselves.

My stop-gap solution was to use memcached as sprockets' cache method (instead of filestore).

This works, however when I want to debug rendering time/iteration within my logs, I don't want memcached running. Ideally I'd like to set the entire app's temp directory to the local file system of the VM instead of the NFS mounted folder that my rails app resides in - unless someone has a better solution.

Comment: I remember this problem with Vagrant! I think I used the rsync file system and it was much faster without problems. I tried NFS, VagrantFS, and others. For this, you can move `tmp` to `/tmp` and add a symbolic link.

Comment: Due to my workflow (make edits in host OS, test changes in VM, push changes in host OS to repository) I can't do this. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: That's not a problem! Vagrants rsync file system keeps it all in synch and is nearly as good as VagrantFS, except without the errors. You just have to run a background process in parallel.

Comment: I have another case, I am running rails into AWS Lambda, I am getting this error ex: `Read-only file system @ apply2files - /app/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/pF/pFfFjKIa9QwojrufCxxwrRGvRT5Bkq14Et0i6oxzMs8.cache`

is there a way to change the cache directory?